# New folder and file permissions are not correct

Tags: user-roles, permissions, ftp, user-access

I have read through a bunch of sites, but I could only find the right permission to set to existing files and folders, but I could not find anything related to the new files and folders to be created.

Whenever I create a new file or folder they will be created with permissions `660` and `770`, so some of the contents are not accessible. For exaple if I install a plugin, it will be installed with `770` and `660` permissions, so I get a `403` error through the javascript console for all assets of the plugin.

Is there a way/plugin, to adjust persmissions to the files and folders to be created in the future, not just the existing ones?

> Please note: I don't have SSH access (or any access, but FTP) to the hosting server.

Comment: Did you check with themes & plugins disabled? If yes and the error persists, you probably have to contact your host. This is not default WordPress behaviour

Comment: I checked it with themes & plugins disabled now, but the problem still persists :(

Comment: This is a site for questions about WordPress, your question seems more suited to https://serverfault.com

Comment: I asked the question there afterwards, no answers though. By the way WordPress is the CMS that tries to fix server issues internally with tweaks and plugins, that's why I think my question fits here, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these two lines to the `wp-config.php` file solved the problem:

```
define('FS_CHMOD_FILE', 0644);
define('FS_CHMOD_DIR', 0755);
```